# Why is copying from a ndarray to another ndarray memory consuming?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, reorderlist

I'm facing a problem when trying to shuffle a multi-dimensional array with numpy.
The problem can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
s=(300000, 3000)
n=s[0]
print ("Allocate")
A=np.zeros(s)
B=np.zeros(s)
print ("Index")
idx = np.arange(n)
print ("Shuffle")
idx = np.random.shuffle(idx)
print ("Arrange")
B[:,:] = A[idx,:] # THIS REQUIRES A LARGE AMOUNT OF MEMORY
```

When running this code (python 2.7 as well as python 3.6 with numpy 1.13.1 on win7 64bit), the execution of the last line of code is requiring a large amount of memory (~ 10 Gb), which sound strange to me.

Actually, I'm expecting the data to be copied from an array to another, both being pre-allocated, so I can understand that the copy will consume time, but not understand why it requires memory.

I guess I do something wrong but don't find what... maybe someone can help me?

Comment: You know that `np.random.shuffle` returns `None` so you just index with `A[None, :]`?

Comment: @MSeifert even correcting the line in question to `np.random.shuffle(idx)` produces the described behaviour. For me on a Mac, the last line increases the peak memory usage from about 24 MB to about 3.5 GB (tested it with `resource.getrusage`).

Comment: Yeah, but it's kind of useless to discuss something that may not do what was/is intended.

Comment: yes you're right... sorry for the mistake, but as pointed out by @Thomas the problem persists when removing the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `numpy` documentation under 'Index arrays':

> NumPy arrays may be indexed with other arrays (or any other sequence-
>   like object that can be converted to an array, such as lists, with the
>   exception of tuples; see the end of this document for why this is).
>   The use of index arrays ranges from simple, straightforward cases to
>   complex, hard-to-understand cases. **For all cases of index arrays, what
>   is returned is a copy of the original data, not a view as one gets for
>   slices.**

In other words, your assumption that your line `B[:,:] = A[idx,:]` (after correcting the line pointed out by @MSeifert) only induces copying of elements from `A` to `B` is not correct. Instead `numpy` first creates a new array from the indexed `A` before copying its elements into `B`.

Why the memory usage changes so much is beyond me. However, looking at your original array shape, `s=(300000,3000)`, this would, for 64 bit numbers, amount to roughly 6.7 GB, if I didn't calculate wrong. Thus creating that additional array, the extra memory usage actually seems plausible.

**EDIT**:

Reacting to the OP's comments, I did a few tests concerning the performance of different ways to assign the shuffled rows of `A` to `B`. First off, here a small test that `B=A[idx,:]` indeed creates a new `ndarray`, not just a view of `A`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b = a[[2,0,1],:]
>>> b
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> b[0]=-5
>>> b
array([[-5, -5, -5],
       [ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

So indeed, assigning new values to `b` leaves `a` unchanged. Then I did a few timing tests concerning the fastest way to shuffle the rows of `A` and getting them into `B`:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import numba as nb

s=(300000, 3000)
A = np.arange(s[0]*s[1]).reshape(s)
idx = np.arange(s[0])

#directly keep the indexed array
def test1(x,idx):  
    return x[idx,:]

#the method of the OP
def test2(x, y, idx):
    y[:,:]=x[idx,:]
    return y

#using a simple for loop, e.g. if only part of the rows should be assigned
def test3(x,y,idx):
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        y[i,:] = x[idx[i],:]
    return y

#like test3, but numba-compiled
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def test4(x,y,idx):
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        y[i,:] = x[idx[i],:]
    return y

B = np.zeros(s)
res = timeit.Timer(
    'test1(A,idx)',
    setup = 'from __main__ import test1, A, idx'
    ).repeat(7,1)

print('test 1:', np.min(res), np.max(res), np.mean(res))

B = np.zeros(s)
res = timeit.Timer(
    'test2(A,B,idx)',
    setup = 'from __main__ import test2, A, B, idx'
    ).repeat(7,1)

print('test 2:', np.min(res), np.max(res), np.mean(res))


B = np.zeros(s)
res = timeit.Timer(
    'test3(A,B,idx)',
    setup = 'from __main__ import test3, A, B, idx'
    ).repeat(7,1)

print('test 3:', np.min(res), np.max(res), np.mean(res))


B = np.zeros(s)
res = timeit.Timer(
    'test4(A,B,idx)',
    setup = 'from __main__ import test4, A, B, idx'
    ).repeat(7,1)

print('test 4:', np.min(res), np.max(res), np.mean(res))
```

The results (min, max, mean) of 7 runs are:

```
test 1: 19.880664938 21.354912988 20.2604536371
test 2: 73.419507756 139.534279557 122.949712777
test 3: 40.030043285 78.001182537 64.7852914216
test 4: 40.001512514 73.397133578 62.0058947516
```

In the end, a simple `for`-loop does not perform too badly, especially if you want to only assign part of the rows, not the entire array. Surprisingly `numba` does not seem to enhance performance.

Comment: @MSeifert Oh, the MB was a typo. And you're right, apparently I can't calculate 64/8 correctly anymore -- I'll fix it ...

Comment: Ok, but 3.4 would have been a perfect explanation for the 10GB: 3.4 for `A`, 3.4 for `B` and 3.4 for the temporary array `A[idx, :]` = 10.2 GB (match!). :)

Comment: @MSeifert That's correct. Maybe it depends on the default type that `np.zeros` uses to create the original array. My assumption was 64-bit floats, but maybe its just 32-bit integers -- that would add up. To share the calculation, first I had `300000*3000*4/1024**3=3.35` and then `300000*3000*8/1024**3=6.71`.

Comment: The default dtype for [`zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) is `float` which is `np.float64` (8 bytes). Maybe the real script isn't what was posted here. :D

Comment: Thank you... I understand, but then, is there a way to perform this copy without creating a temporary object.In C-like code it would be something like for (int i=0,i<N;++i) B[i,:]=A[idx[i],:]; which I can't code in python for performance reasons...

Comment: @davidguez If you want to shuffle all rows of `A`, basically the line `B=A[idx,:]` would already do what you want (you can at the same time leave out the line `B=np.zeros(...)`). If you want to only re-assign part of the rows, I think it would depend a lot on the specific problem, but I'm sure that a suitable solution can be found :)

Comment: @davidguez please see the edit to my answer -- hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the copying the problem is that your arrays are huge:

```
>>> 300000 * 3000 * 8 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024  # 8 byte floats, 300000 * 3000 elements converted to GB
6.705522537231445
```

So the arrays are almost 7GB huge. So how come it only triggers at the assignment line `B[:,:] = A[idx,:]`?

That's because `zeros` doesn't actually allocate the array until you want to use it. And you don't use it until you index it (in case of `A`: `A[idx, :]`) or assign to it (in case of `B`: `B[:,:] =`).

So there's nothing strange going on, it's just the amount of memory you actually need for `A` and `B`.

Comment: you beat me to it :D

Comment: Thanks... but then how to actually pre-allocate the memory ? Thanks for you help!

Comment: @davidguez You could use [`np.full(shape, 0)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) that immediately allocates the memory. :)

Comment: Also you could use `A.take(idx, out=B)`. That could avoid the temporary copy by directly writing into `B`.

Comment: @davidguez No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it resolved your issue :)

Comment: and I guess, in my case, I should write A.take(idx,0,out=B) since my index is not the flatten index of A but the one along the 0th axis... right ?